# Find different elements with BeautifulSoup that have the same class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i am trying to **scrape** 2 elements from this url : https://www.welcometothejungle.com/fr/companies/dataiku/jobs/ai-solutions-manager-life-science_london_DATAI_a2jpa5o . CDI and LONDON, the issue here is that :

- They have the same classe
- They are in the same div

for London :

```
<li class="sc-1qc42fc-0 kExFnG"><span role="img" class="sc-1qc42fc-3 heity"><i name="location" class="sc-kmATbt bGKMNx"></i></span><span class="sc-1qc42fc-2 jmExaK">London</span></li>
```

for CDI :

```
<li class="sc-1qc42fc-0 kExFnG"><span role="img" class="sc-1qc42fc-3 heity"><i name="contract" class="sc-kmATbt jYkMSd"></i></span><span class="sc-1qc42fc-2 jmExaK"><span>CDI</span>&nbsp;</span></li>
```

I can see that both html codes have one thing that this different, the "i": one's name is location, the other contract, but i can't seem to find a way tu use this info in order to **scrape** the correct element

How can i manage to do a `soup.find` that will allow me to extract bot element "CDI and London" ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, this should work for you:

```py
# Get all the children of the parent of the first li with that class
lis = list(soup.find_all('li', attrs={'class': 'sc-1qc42fc-0 kExFnG'})[0].parent.children)

fields = {}
for li in lis:
    fields[li.find('i').get('name')] = li.text.strip()

print(fields)
```

Output:

```py
{'contract': 'CDI', 'location': 'London'}
```

Comment: ok i see, but what if i only want, for example : "London" without the 'location' ?

Comment: Try `print(fields['location'])` or `print(fields['contract'])`.